# How to create dependency dropdown menu in react js

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, dropdown

How we create dependency menu in react js .
for ex: there are two dropdown menu named branch and subject respectively . In that I want if select branch from 1st dropdown then the subject of that branch only shown in 2nd dropdown .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by using condition. Simply use the following pattern set conditional rendering of component or data you want to display.

```
  {(branchOneClicked)?
    // Render your second branch
    :
    // else render something Else
    }
```

Or, You can put a state with numbering. Let's say on branch clicked, change state and if that state === 1 (or the one you specified) render second one relating to it.

PS: It'll be more helpful to give you answer if you provide us code. Thank you